# How to determine local cloned branch name and push changes back - Git

Tags: git, github

Alright, I come from SVN background.

I am working on a project, the code of which is maintained on git. 
All I have is a clone URL. So I did 
`git clone repo_url repo_name`.

What is the preferred way to make changes/work on this copy. Like do I need to do git checkout someBranch etc ? Then How can I  push changes back to git.

Are the following steps right to commit and push back into the remote repository ?

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -m "message"`
3. `git push remotebranch localbranch`

If they are then what is the localbranchname or remotebranchname to be substituted as?

Comment: Once you've cloned the repo locally, it checks out master by default. You can work on it or create a branch and once done just do `git push origin master` or if you worked on a branch then merge the branch first `git merge <branchName>`

Comment: Really, you should ask to the other collaborators on the project. There are various possible organization options, and your coworkers should tell you how they chose to organize themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your remote by this command

```
git remote
```

Most of the time `git remote` is set to `origin`

Now the next question, how do you check what the origin is

```
git remote show origin
```

This will return something as follows where you can find the git server for the repository, it will also list the branches which the remote has:

```
* remote origin
  URL: me@remote.example.com:~/something.git
  Remote branch merged with 'git pull' while on branch master
    master
  Tracked remote branch
    master
```

Now your first question was what is the preferred of way making changes:

You should make a local branch by

```
git checkout -b "your Branch name"
```

Make changes in this branch and commit them when you want. Now once all the changes are verified, merge them into the main branch(usually its master). So for merging what you'll do is as follows(i'll assume your main branch is master):
git chekcout master
git merge "your Branch name"

That's it. Now you can push you master to the server by simply:

```
git push
```

or

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: No no. something is missing in this answer. How do command, `git remote ` knows about which Url to clone? And the rest of the branching you explained. Does this mean by default my repo_name is master as local and not repo_name as I mentioned in my question?

Answer (score 0):

To check git repo:

```
# Any of the below works
vim REPO/.git/config # You can even change it from here
git remove -v
```

To push changes:

```
git add . # this will add all from the `.` directory
git commit -m "My changes" # or `git commit` for interactive editor
git push
```

To switch branch:

```
git checkout <branch>
```

Enjoy

Comment: I didn't understood last line. Why is it necessary or if optional , the use of it  ? And neither the very first line

Comment: `checkout` is needed if you ware working on different branches. But if you only have master, then you don't need it ;)